# How to restore corrupted .IDB files on a MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

I currently have all the old `.frm` and `.idb` files from a MySQL server (actually the entire data directory). The server itself has been deleted by the user in his troubleshooting and he has installed a new server which he wants me to essentially restore all the old information to.

Currently, I have been trying to use the
`alter table table_name discard tablespace`,
`alter table table_name import tablespace` method
to move the data to the new server,
but I keep getting an error saying:

> ERROR 1932 (42S02): Table '*table_name*' doesn't exist in engine

If the `alter table table_name import tablespace` command
is run again, it returns:

> ERROR 1034 (HY000): Index for table '*table_name*' is corrupt; try to repair it.

This has led me to try dumping the table. 
However, when you run `mysqldump.exe`, you get:

> mysqldump.exe: Couldn't execute 'show fields from *table_name*':
>   Table '*database_name.table_name*' doesn't exist in engine (1932)

How can I go about recovering data from these corrupted files?

Comment: Are you using MySQL Workbench and Data Import/Restore on the old folder?

Comment: Have you tried running the server against a copy of the backed-up data dir, using mysqldump to export it, then import the file when running the server against the real (new) data dir?

Comment: Eugen's method has worked best so far, about 20-30% of the data was lost per table due to the corruption but this solved the issue.